# What's the meaning of "appeal to" in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, definition

> Part 1 is mainly phatic: contact is established by offering information and producing a positive impression on the reader, using mainly nonverbal **means which appeal to the** cliché of a prototypical Spanish coastal village, thus responding more to the expectations of foreigners than of Spaniards even in the original;

What's the meaning of "appeal to" in this context? And what is the meaning of "appeal" as a noun in linguistics?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of **appeal to** as "asking for a response from".

**appeal** is a verb there, not a noun.

If a work of art or essay or speech **appeals to the emotions** it seeks to raise an emotional response from the audience.

I don't consider the sentence you've quoted an example of fine writing. What the writer means to say, I think, is that "part 1 .... **invokes** the foreigner's stereotypical image of a Spanish coastal village". That is, it "summons up" that stereotype and all of the associations it may have in the minds of foreigners.

Comment: Usually, an image is evoked not invoked.

Comment: @malaprop:  The image can be evoked or invoked.  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22invokes%20the%20image%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en